# Split numpy values by indices resulting in irregular shape

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

Here's what I want to achieve with numpy and have no idea how. To be clear, I'd like to do it as concisely as possible.

```
# shape (5, 2)
data = np.array([
    [10, 20]
    [30, 50]
    [10, 10]
    [5, 13]
    [7, 7]
])

# shape (5,)
target = np.array([0, 2, 1, 0, 2])

# how to achieve this in a more numpy way
# shape(3, 2)
result = np.zeros((target.max() + 1, data.shape[1]))
for i in range(result.shape[0])):
    result[i] = data[np.where(target == i)].mean(axis=0)
```

I know it can be a one liner:

```
result = np.array([data[np.where(target == i)].mean(axis=0)
                   for i in range(target.max() + 1)])
```

Thanks

EDIT : There's was a typo in the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** We can use `np.add.at` -

```
def binmean_addat(data, target):
    result = np.zeros((target.max() + 1, data.shape[1]))
    np.add.at(result, target,data)
    grouped_count = np.bincount(target)
    out = result/np.bincount(target)[:,None]
    out[grouped_count==0] = 0
    return out
```

**Approach #2 :** We can also leverage `matrix-multiplication` -

```
def binmean_dot(data, target):
    grouped_sum = (target == np.arange(target.max() + 1)[:,None]).dot(data)
    grouped_count = np.bincount(target)
    out = np.true_divide(grouped_sum,grouped_count[:,None])
    out[grouped_count==0] = 0
    return out
```

**Approach #3 :** With `np.add.reduceat` -

```
def binmean_reduceat(data, target):
    sidx = target.argsort()
    grouped_count = np.bincount(target)
    grouped_sum = np.add.reduceat(data[sidx],np.r_[0,grouped_count[:-1].cumsum()])
    out = np.true_divide(grouped_sum,grouped_count[:,None])
    out[grouped_count==0] = 0
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [45]: data
Out[45]: 
array([[10, 20],
       [30, 50],
       [10, 10],
       [ 5, 13],
       [ 7,  7]])

In [46]: target
Out[46]: array([0, 2, 1, 0, 2])

In [47]: binmean_addat(data, target)
Out[47]: 
array([[ 7.5, 16.5],
       [10. , 10. ],
       [18.5, 28.5]])
```

---

For kids playing `code-golf`, here's two (one is a modified version from posted question and another from one of the earlier ones in this post) -

App #1 -

```
(data.T.dot(target[:,None]==range(target.max()+1))/(np.bincount(target)+0.0)).T
```

App #2 -

```
np.array([data[target==t].mean(0) for t in range(target.max()+1)])
```

Comment: Nice appraoches, but I was looking for something as concise as what I did D:

Answer (score 0):

The numpy_indexed package (disclaimer: I am its author) was created to efficiently and concisely solve problems such as these:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
unique, result = npi.group_by(target).mean(data)
```